# CORS-cross-origin error on dynamic load of resource

Tags: google-chrome, cors, es6-modules, rollupjs, javascript-import

I face the error:

```sh
TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier '../static/myJson.json'. 
The base URL is about:blank because import() is called from a CORS-cross-origin script.
```

at runtime when the page loads in browser and tries to dynamically `import` a `json` file.

The piece of code:

```
// myCode.ts
export const MY_JSON_FILEPATH = "";

window.addEventListener("load", async () => {
  try {
    const myData = await import(MY_JSON_FILEPATH); // replaced by rollup-replace
  } catch (error) {
    console.warn(`Unable to load json file`, error);
    return;
  }
}
```

which is loaded by the html template:

```html
#index.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta
            name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no"
            charset="UTF-8"
        />
        <script src="myCode.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

When I was doing the same from another source file which imports the JSON statically, everything was fine with no CORS issue. But, since I changed it to use rollup to try to dynamically load the resource file at runtime, I'm facing this error.

I post the whole setup in case I miss something there.
Not sure where this CORS comes from.

Using:

```
"typescript": "^4.6.3"
"rollup": "^2.60.2",
"rollup-plugin-typescript2": "^0.31.2",
"rollup-plugin-replace": "^2.2.0",
"rollup-plugin-commonjs": "^10.1.0",
```

Typescript is setup with:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es6"
    ],
    "target": "es6",
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "rootDirs": ["./src",  "../../../config/*.json"],
    "module": "ESNext",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

And rollup:

```js
import commonjs from "@rollup/plugin-commonjs";
import json from "@rollup/plugin-json";
import replace from "@rollup/plugin-replace";
import typescript from "rollup-plugin-typescript2";
import { nodeResolve } from "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve";
import { createBasicConfig } from "@open-wc/building-rollup";
import merge from "deepmerge";
import path from "path";


const pathResolve = (loc) => path.resolve(__dirname, loc);
const externalJsonFile = path.resolve("./static/myJson.json");

const nodeModules = "node_modules/**";

const baseConfig = createBasicConfig();

export default merge(baseConfig, [
    {
        input: pathResolve("src/index.ts"),
        output: [
            {
                file: pathResolve("dist/index.es.js"),
                format: "esm",
            },
            {
                file: pathResolve("dist/index.js"),
                format: "cjs",
            },
        ],
        external: [externalJsonFile],
        plugins: [
            nodeResolve([".ts"], { browser: true }),
            typescript(),
            replace({
                MY_JSON_FILEPATH: `"${externalJsonFile}"`,
            }),
            commonjs({
                include: nodeModules,
                extensions: [".js", ".ts", ".mjs", ".json"],
            }),
        ],
        context: "window",
    },
}
```

Comment: I can’t suggest a solution for this, but for what it’s worth and for the record here,  https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/09e82ae40f8408bd6e7b4b4cd011b7447edc1ba2 and https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/5751 are where info about the background for underlying cause can be found. The Chrome change that causes the error message cited in the question first shipped in Chrome 97.

Answer (score 0):

When accessing files using the "file://" protocol directly in the browser, you may encounter a CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) error. This error occurs because the browser enforces the same-origin policy, which restricts interactions between resources loaded via the "file://" protocol and resources from different origins.
You can use a local server: Set up a local server (e.g., using Node.js or Python's SimpleHTTPServer) and serve your files from there. By accessing your files through the local server's URL (e.g., "http://localhost:8000"), you can avoid the CORS error.

Recommend: https://github.com/JacksonTian/anywhere